# SwiftUI DragGesture() get start location on screen

Tags: swiftui, draggesture

I want to make a view "swipeable", however this view only covers a small share of the whole screen. Doing:

```
var body: some View {
    
    ZStack {
        Text("ABC")
            .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged(onChanged))
    }
}

func onChanged(value: DragGesture.Value) {
    print(value.startLocation)
    print("onChanged", value.location)
}
```

Gives me relative values where the user has swiped - however, without knowing the exact location of the view, I'm unable to know where the user's touch is on the screen.

In other words, when the `Text` is in the center of the screen, going all the way to the right edge gives 200px. But let's say the Text moved to the left, then it would be almost 400. I tried putting another gesture on the ZStack to save the initial value, however it appears you can't have multiple gestures within each other.

How can I make the listener translate the values so the left edge is 0 and the right edge is displayWidth in px, regardless of where the Text is?

Comment: So you only want to start the gesture when dragging the `Text`, but get the global coordinates relative to the screen?

Comment: Hey George, that's it, exactly. The only other way I can think of is to use GeometryReader and compare coordinates for a DragGesture spanning over the whole screen but GeometryReader always messed up stuff and it sounds like a really hacky workaround

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of coordinate spaces, and use that with `DragGesture`.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var location: CGPoint = .zero

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            Text("ABC")
                .background(Color.red)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .named("screen")).onChanged(onChanged)
                )

            Text("Location: (\(location.x), \(location.y))")
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .coordinateSpace(name: "screen")
    }

    private func onChanged(value: DragGesture.Value) {
        location = value.location
    }
}
```